# Charged if Amazon EC2 instance is on but do nothing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using a g2.2xlarge, quite pricey, so I'm concerned about the bill. I just use it to train some machine learning models, not using it as a webserver. If after running all the training, I don't use it anymore but leave it on, i.e, when I go to the console, I see the status as 'running' but CPU meter already drops, past 16:30 a bit (as screenshot), do I still get charged for the whole time (as of now, midnight my time, its status is still `running`), or only up to the time where the CPU drops?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EC2 instance are billed by instance-hours as long as they are in **Running** state. Actual CPU usage (or other metrics) have no affect on your bill.

To save costs when not using the instances, you can stop the EC2 instances. You won't be billed in "Stopped" state.

Comment: thanks, you stopped me from breaking the bank! Gosh, it's four days already.

Answer (score 2):

For On Demand EC2 instances, you pay for the Hours, so regardless of its utilization, you will get billed hourly. Even you stop the instance (Unless Terminated) you will be charged for EBS storage.